# Git protocol in Apache Commons VFS

Tags: java, git, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

Do you know about any implementation of git:// protocol for Apache Commons VFS in Java?

Of course Git isn't among officially supported file systems, see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html — but I can't believe there is no impl at all. Tried to google it and found nothing usable.

Since Git can generally be seen as file system with VCS features on top of it, I guess it shouldn't be that hard to create an VFS module. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uberfire/vfs-jgit
```

Actually, the uberfire has a implementation of jgit virtual file system, it doesn't release for long time, although it works for redhat jbpm kie server:

```
 https://github.com/kiegroup/appformer
```

Comment: Looks good. Original request has been lost in time but I will try to spare some time to look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mmounirou/commons-vfs-git appears to be a commons-vfs implementation using jgit.